# need replace id_parent on name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query:

```
SELECT Strtbmovie.id_parent,
       Strtbuser.Name  as 'Name',
       Strtbmovie.Name as Movie,
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountBeginWatch),
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountEndWatch),
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountBeginTest),
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountEndTest),
       max(Strtbmovieatt.CountTest)
FROM   Strtbmovie
       INNER JOIN Strtbmovieatt
         ON Strtbmovie.Idmovie = Strtbmovieatt.Idmovie
       INNER JOIN Strtbuser
         ON Strtbmovieatt.Iduser = Strtbuser.Iduser
GROUP  BY Strtbmovie.Name,
          Strtbuser.Name,
          Strtbmovie.id_parent
```

How to replace in this query columns id_parent  on name knowing id_parent?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You want to get the name from another table or something? If so what are your table structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an extra `INNER JOIN` with the Strtbmovie table `ON Strtbmovie.id_parent = StrtbmovieParent.Idmovie` and the group by the actual name as follows:

```
SELECT StrtbmovieParent.Name as ParentName,
       Strtbuser.Name  as 'Name',
       Strtbmovie.Name as Movie,
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountBeginWatch),
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountEndWatch),
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountBeginTest),
       sum(Strtbmovieatt.CountEndTest),
       max(Strtbmovieatt.CountTest)
FROM   Strtbmovie
       INNER JOIN Strtbmovieatt
         ON Strtbmovie.Idmovie = Strtbmovieatt.Idmovie
       INNER JOIN Strtbuser
         ON Strtbmovieatt.Iduser = Strtbuser.Iduser
       INNER JOIN Strtbmovie as StrtbmovieParent
         ON Strtbmovie.id_parent = StrtbmovieParent.Idmovie
GROUP  BY Strtbmovie.Name,
          Strtbuser.Name,
          StrtbmovieParent.Name
```